# How do I make sure my css property top is consistent across all browsers?

Tags: html, css

I have a css property, top:395px that positions a button on the page. When I run the code in Microsoft Edge the button is in the correct location however when I run in other browsers like Firefox, Chrome, and Safari the placement off. I understand that each browser has different standards on how the code is read, but I can’t seem to make it consistent. I used an image of an open road as the background  so you can clearly see how the position of the button changes. In Edge seven doted lines are visible but in others like Firefox four are visible. Can anyone please help? Thank you in advance. P.s. I do not own the rights to the image I am just using it as an example.

> `

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 
}


body {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/73kAdwa.jpeg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  }


.parent{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}

button {
  all: unset;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 17px; 
   z-index: 3;
   display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 40px;
   position: fixed;
   top:395px;

}


#button {
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #58cc02;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 0 #58a700;

}

#button:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}



 .bg {
  position: fixed;
  width :300px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 17px;
  outline: #58cc02 solid 3px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  animation : pulse 1.5s infinite alternate;
  top:395px; 
}


@keyframes pulse{
0% {
transform :scale(1,1);

}
100% {
transform : scale(1.1, 1.20);

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <title>Pulsing Button</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parent">

  <button id="button" >
    Click ME
  </button> 
  
  <div class="bg"></div>
 
  

</div>


<script src="script.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Your background image is changing, not your button position.  In any case, what exactly is it that you're trying to do?  What do you expect to happen if your page is loaded on a device/window that isn't even 300px tall?  Are you *sure* that you don't just want to place the button in the top third center of the page?  Because that'd be something you could do easily via flexbox.

Comment: Just use a percentage on `top` rather than a fixed pixel value. That way it will adjust to the height of the viewport.

Comment: The way you have sized your imaage (100% of width and height of body) will make it distorted on different devices. Measure where you want the button to be in terms of % of the full image. Then place the image in a way which ensures the part you want the button to cover is definitely within any viewport (perhaps centrally). Have all the image as background (which means some of it may well be outside the body).

Comment: @A Haworth Thank You for your help it worked!

Answer (score -2):

Try using REM units for your "top" selector instead of pixels, pixels are fixed units, so it will be fixed to be 395px's from the top of whatever browser you're using, whereas REM units are responsive and fluid, so that should fix your issue, let me know if it does (: